# XHR IE7 Operation Aborted JSON Error

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to send an AJAX post request in IE 7, but I'm getting an "Operation Aborted" error, seemingly from the JSON I'm sending, even though everything seems right. I've been messing around with this for an hour or so now, and haven't made any progress, so thought I would post it here to see if anyone could see anything wrong with it.

The "Operation Aborted" error keeps mentioning DOM loading issues, but I only see it when I try to make this post request, so I imagine it's something different in this situation.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", url, false);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
try {
    request.send('{"param":"value"}');
} catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing `request.send('{"param":"value"}');` to `request.send('{ "param" : "value" }')` fixed the issue, sigh.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the URL your trying to post data to simply doesn't work on IE7. Try updating to IE8.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927917

Stuff like this happens when a script tries to alter an element that hasn't finished loading yet. This website explains it quite well:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/04/23/what-happened-to-operation-aborted.aspx

Comment: yea, I saw that, but my script doesn't alter any html elements. unfortunately, this was IE6/7 specific -- so upgrading wasn't an option. thanks for your thoughts though! it ended up being a json issue.